# Why does my XPATH code work on sites, but not in the python compiler?

Tags: python, xpath

I just wanted to know what this error was in the response of my HTML scraper in python. It says the elementtree is not initialized and that it's missing the root.
If someone knows what this is and could tell me what this means and a solution that would be great. Thank you.

## Here's my code

```
import lxml.html
import requests
url =  "https://quizlet.com/495157354/spell"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) #stream=True)
print(response)
response.raw.decode_content = True
tree = lxml.html.parse(response.raw)
wordtodefine = tree.xpath('//*[@id="js-spellPrompt"]/span').text
print(tree.xpath)
print(wordtodefine)
input("Enter")
```

## Here's the response

```
<Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word.py", line 62, in <module>
    wordtodefine = tree.xpath('//*[@id="js-spellPrompt"]/span').text
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 2292, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1870, in lxml.etree._ElementTree._assertHasRoot
AssertionError: ElementTree not initialized, missing root
```

Comment: Might be a downloading problem (missing headers or user-agent). What happens if you try to parse the file locally with `from lxml import etree; tree = etree.parse("yourdata.xml")` ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? For example, are the contents of `tree` what you expect?

Comment: The contents of ```tree``` are what I expect. I'll check the downloading problem and see if I can parse the data from my own computer. Thanks!